# DRUPAL-7: hook declaration missing

Tags: php, drupal-7

Goodmorning everyone,

I'm new in Drupal.
I hope don't ask a stupid question.
I'm working with Drupal 7 and I need to edit a custom module for my company developed by another developer.
This is a piece of code where I use "theme" function.
This code is under **"sites/all/modules/gestione_attivita_attivita/gestione_attivita_attivita.module"**

```
function gestione_attivita_attivita_block_search_attivita($tipo_ricerca) {

  $block['subject'] = "";

  $ricerca = gestione_attivita_ricerca_fetchAll($tipo_ricerca);

  $block['content'] = theme('ricerca_attivita', array(
    'items' => $ricerca,
    'tipo_ricerca' => $tipo_ricerca
  ));
  return $block; 
}
```

I know that should exist `"ricerca_attivita"` hook declared somehere in my files.
I'v been looking for something like `"['ricerca_attivita'] = array("` or similar words or sub-words in all my files of my site folder but it doesn't exist.
The only thing I know is that under :
`"sites/all/themes/customModuleOfmyCompany/templates"` 
there are several tpl files and in particular one called `"ricerca_attivita.tpl.php"` that work and receives data from theme function but I don't know how this is possible.
I don't know who tell to theme call to go on another folder on another path and use "ricerca_attivita.tpl.php" and not foo.tpl.php for example.
Is there anyone that can help me?

Another thing:

Going under includes/theme.inc and debugginng it I have this printing hook info:

```
array (
  'template' => 'ricerca_attivita',
  'path' => 'sites/all/themes/customtheme/templates',
  'type' => 'theme_engine',
  'theme path' => 'sites/all/themes/customtheme',
  'preprocess functions' => 
  array (
    0 => 'template_preprocess',
    1 => 'contextual_preprocess',
  ),
  'process functions' => 
  array (
    0 => 'template_process',
    1 => 'ctools_process',
    2 => 'rdf_process',
  ),
)
```

but I don't know who is that declare it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the developer module for themers https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer

And about theming function, did you search for this function inside the themes folder?

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for the delay, I simply forgot to clear the cache.After doing that

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for the delay, I simply forgot to clear the cache. After doing that and after reading http://www.enzoazzolini.it/guidadrupal/themeregistry and in particular after understand how drupal search for custom theme  works  I undesrstand all.